# Method reference in java

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I'm exploring method reference in java, and just curious if following can be converted to a method reference

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
list.forEach(item -> new SomeClass(item).someMethod(item));
```

I tried the following, but that didn't work

```
list.forEach(SomeClass::new::someMethod);
```

Comment: No, `::` does not work with "pipelining".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is it possible to use the object created using `list.forEach(SomeClass::new)` for calling the `someMethod`?

Comment: Why would you include `item` again in the `someMethod` call? If that's not necessary, you could do something like `list.stream().map(SomeClass::new).forEach(SomeClass::someMethod)`.

Comment: If you want, you can declare a new method that does what you want and then use a referrence to it.

Comment: you can't do use telescopically method reference , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1

Comment: @OleV.V. yup that would be more sensible than what I'm trying. I was checking if there is a way to achieve it in single call without putting it in the method.

Comment: @Henrik in the code snippet you give it appears `someMethod` will be a static method, I want to call the `someMethod` on the object that can be created in previous `map(SomeClass::new)` call.
However I'm getting a feeling that is not the way the `map` function works.

Comment: @ketub: `someMethod` is not required to be `static` in my example. Try it out in a unit test or a small program.

Answer (score 3):

There are four types of method reference, that you can use based on java specification , you can use only this type method reference

1. Reference to a static method       **Class::staticMethodName**
2. Reference to a constructor         **ClassName::new**
3. Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type  **lass::instanceMethodName**
4. Reference to an instance method of a particular object **object::instanceMethodName**

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to resolve the issue in the way you provided. But it could be done by defining the `someMethod` method as `static`:

```
list.forEach(item -> SomeClass.someMethod(item));
list.forEach(SomeClass::someMethod);
```

The statement `SomeClass::new::someMethod` is incorrect. 
Strictly speaking, `SomeClass::new` refers to a piece of constructor code (like a `Consumer`), it does not return a new instance while you need an object to make a method reference `SomeClassinstance::someMethod`.

EDIT:
I really don't see any advantages of the approach:

```
map(SomeClass::new).forEach(SomeClass::someMet‌hod)
```

because it leads to creation a portion of useless `SomeClass` instances with `item`s that also will not be used.

Comment: okay, so in that case as ole-v-v suggested, i would be better off creating a method and handle all this from there.

Answer (score 2):

Would this be an option may be?

```
Function<Integer, SomeClass> f = SomeClass::new;
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
list.forEach(i -> f.apply(i).someMethod());
```

And obviously a method to do what you want is another way to go:

```
private static void method(int item) {
    new SomeClass(item).someMethod();
}

list.forEach(YourClass::method);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of following code. Although, it is not using method reference but should be more readable than imperative style coding.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
Function<Integer, SomeClass> someClass = SomeClass::new;
BiConsumer<SomeClass, Integer> someMethod = SomeClass::someMethod;
list.forEach(item -> someMethod.accept(someClass.apply(item), item));
```